# How to use state parameter in fetch url correctly?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Hello I have problem to set state variable in url parameter. I have tried few example I found in internet, but no one works for me.

I tried this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      channelId: []
    };
  }
     componentDidMount() {
          this.setState({ channelId: '1ae2275e-2ca2-42cb-be13-e97b59fbae13' });
        }
    componentWillMount() {
        fetch(
          `http://localhost:8080/api/channel/${this.state.channelId}`)
    .then...
```

And this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      channelId: []
    };
 componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ channelId: '1ae2275e-2ca2-42cb-be13-e97b59fbae13' });
    }
componentWillMount() {
    fetch(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/channel/'+this.state.channelId)
.then...
```

None of them are setting value in url. Maybe someone could tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you set channelId in constructor ? or its just an example for question ?

Comment: @Veloceo, but I need to switch between channels, how could i rerender on constructor change?

Answer (score 0):

componentWillMount called before componentDidMount
-> so in componentWillMount, this.state.channelId = []

I think, you should set state of channelId in ComponentWillMount and call api in componentDidMount

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      channelId: ''
    };
 componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({ channelId: '1ae2275e-2ca2-42cb-be13-e97b59fbae13' });
    }
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/channel/'+this.state.channelId)
.then...
```

And with react 16, react doesn't recommend using componentWillMount in new code (Details: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing is to set channelId to a string and not an array.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      channelId: ''
     }
```

Let me ask why you want to use componentWillMount... From my experience, it sometimes adds a lifecycle that is not necessarily useful. 
Have you tried

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      channelId: ''
    };
    
    componentDidMount() {
       this.getChannelId()
    }
    
    getChannelId() {
         this.setState({
            channelId: '1ae2275e-2ca2-42cb-be13-e97b59fbae13'
        });
        return fetch( `http://localhost:8080/api/channel/${this.state.channelId}`)
            .then(res => {
             // your code
             })
    }
```

?

I used a "similar" approach for an app of mine:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect} from 'react-redux';
import { API_BASE_URL } from '../config';
import { Weekday, Weekendday } from './Day';
import './Availability.css';

const currentUserId = localStorage.getItem("id");

export class Availability extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            availability: {},
            loading: false,
            error: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadAvailability()
    }


    loadAvailability() {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        });
        return fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/employee/${currentUserId}/availability`)
            .then(res => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    return Promise.reject(res.statusText);
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(availability => {
                console.log(availability)
                this.setState({
                    availability,
                    loading: false
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({
                    error: 'Could not load availability list',
                    load: false
                })
                console.log(this.state.error, err)
            })
        }
        
        ...
```

Also do you mind sharing the rest of your code for that component so we can see when you need another change of state?
Thanks!